# How to develop third party module in Squid?

Tags: squid

I plan to use Squid as a proxy and need the functionality of allowing/blocking HTTPS requests based on the website URL and request body content. I think the feature can be implemented in a separate third-party module rather than modifying the source code of Squid.

On the [Third Party Modules in Squid](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ThirdPartyModules#third-party-modules-in-squid) page, it mentions

> Squid offers many different interfaces and API for extension, and has for quite some time. The number and power of these interfaces has grown in time, as has their usefulness.

What're those APIs? I can't find any documentation about them for writing extension for Squid.